# the html jquery function is not working on keydown event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

im trying to create an autosuggestion feature in jquery(just experimental- jquery noob), im using the $(el).html function to render out the data that is being served:

```
$("#suggestions").addClass("active");
     var words = $(this).val();
     var results = searchData(questions,words);
     $("#suggestions").html(function () {
            _.each(results, function(q, key){
                return "<p>" + q.question + "</p>"; // problem is here
            });
        });
```

the full working code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/HSBWt/6/
i cant seem to know what going wrong?

Comment: What should it be doing that it isn't?

Comment: its meant to show #suggestions, which is intially hidden, and render out data from the questions array, its like autosuggestion. but its not doing it, i know the problem is inside the .html function :)

Comment: In my experience html() works fine in keydown, are you positive that your code is actually putting something in the .html()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/HSBWt/9/

Use the `map` function to get back an array of the objects

Comment: Your solution isn't using jQuery's `.map()`. It's using the native one.

Comment: My mistake. Never realized it was vanilla

Answer (score 3):

The problem is your `each` statement inside `html` function.

`We can break the $.each() loop at a particular iteration by making the callback function return false. Returning non-false is the same as a continue statement in a for loop; it will skip immediately to the next iteration.`
[reference](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)
Fix the following code:

```
var suggestions;
_.each(results, function(q, key){
    suggestions += "<p>" + q.question + "</p>";
});
return suggestions;
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ricardolohmann/HSBWt/7/)

Answer (score 0):

The result from `_each` is not being used in `html`. You need to save and **return** the resulting string:

```
var results = [];
_.each(results, function(q, key){
  console.log(q.question);
  results.push("<p>" + q.question + "</p>");
});
return results.join('');
```